# Wordpress Rss Feed URLs not Validating on any external applications and Rss feed widget

Tags: php, wordpress, rss

My Rss Feed Urls of my wordpress website are

```
http://www.engineershub.in/newhome/forums/forum/jntu-kakinada-updates/feed
http://www.engineershub.in/newhome/forums/forum/jntu-anantapur/feed
http://www.engineershub.in/newhome/forums/forum/jntu-hyderabad/feed
http://www.engineershub.in/newhome/feed
```

I Have Used these Feed Url's in Android & Windows Applications and in some Wordpress Widgets

I don't Know what happened suddenly, Android & Windows applications stopped syncing and wordpress widgets showing this following error

```
RSS Error: A feed could not be found at http://www.engineershub.in/newhome/forums/forum/jntu-hyderabad/feed. A feed with an invalid mime type may fall victim to this error, or SimplePie was unable to auto-discover it.. Use force_feed() if you are certain this URL is a real feed.
```

and when I am trying to check validation of these urls in thirdparty applications then I am getting a error "INVALID FEED" but when I directly open these URLs in browser, they are opening

I Have tried all the links in google to find a solution but failed, Now all my Mobile Applications stopped working, Please some one help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Have searched all over google but did not find a solution. . .

I Have analysed that .htaccess file on my server are effected. . . . I was unable to edit .htaccess file . . .so I deleted and created a new .htaccess file solved my problem . . . now rss feed is working fine . . . .